# how to combine two signals with different frequencies in time domain

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I collected the communication signals of unman vehicle by using two software defined radio reconfigurable devices. Since each RF receiver has a maximum instantaneous bandwidth of 40 MHz, both receivers must be operated simultaneously to at capture  WiFi (i.e. 80 MHz2) where the first receiver captures the lower half of the frequency band, and the second, records the upper half. 
[collected signals in time domain, the y-axis means the amplitude.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNTld.jpg)

how can I combine these two signals together in the time domain? one idea is that I firstly transform signals into frequency domain respectively and contact them, then use IFFT to transform the signal back into time domain.but i am worried that these operations may damage the original information contained in the signals.

Thank you for any kind answers~

Comment: XL means the lower band signal and XH means the upper band signal

Comment: The FFT will not damage your signal.

Comment: It sounds like a good plan to follow